# When rendering EJS files in Javascript, it turns wordwrap lines of vscode to <br/>?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, ejs

TL;DR EJS Converts VSCode line wraps to 
 tags

I wrote a program in Node and I used EJS for converting/generating dynamic html. But problem start to appear when vs code/prettier wraps the source code lines. When I render those files with EJS it converts those line breaks of vs code to 
 and ads a lot of white spaces. It also adds double quotations around around string.

EJS CODE

```html
<p> Hello <% username %>, how  //assume vs code wrap it
are you doing?  </p>
```

Generated HTML

```html
<p> 
"Hello stranger, how <br/>
how are you?"
<p>
```

I use ejs renderFile method to create html from ejs.

Comment: Can you include the code where you render the ejs file?

Comment: So far I understand the ejs is, that when you pass variables to your ejs file you should use `<p> Hello <%= username %>, how are you doing?</p>`  But like @mousetail already asked for, can you hand in some more code